# MATLAB generate vector with formula of index

Tags: matlab, vector, octave

What is a narrow way to generate something like this:

```
temp = zeros(C);
for i = 1:C
    temp(i) = f(i);
end
```

where the f(.) is some formula.

Comment: `temp = f(1:C)`  ‍‍‍‍‍‍ ‍‍ ‍‍‍‍‍‍ ‍‍

Comment: Make sure that `f` supports element-wise operations (i.e. `.*` instead of `*`, etc.).  Doing what @Sardar_Usama suggests without element-wise support will give you some nasty surprises.

Answer (score 0):

You can [vectorize your function](https://nl.mathworks.com/help/matlab/matlab_prog/vectorization.html), in which case you can issue

```
temp = f(1:C);
```

If that is too cumbersome, you can use

```
temp = arrayfun(@f, 1:C);
```

which can be a bit slower.